# support 64-bit ,set valid Architectures to armv8 is right?

Tags: ios, xcode

If I use standard architecture *(armv7,arm64) -$(ARCHS_STANARD)* in a project. Does that project support *64-bit* when I set valid Architectures to *armv7 armv7s armv8* ?

Comment: i think there is no armv8

Comment: @parvind : I dont know either. And I will set valid Architectures to armv7 armv7s arm64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `arm64` is the 64bit architecture. When you set Standard architecture, you get `armv7` and `arm64` which are 32bit and 64bit architectures.